# Bicep runCommands resource with parameters

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to figure out how the runCommands resource works when you want to provide parameters.

According to the documentation you can provide parameters & protectedParameters properties, but there is no documentation about how to use them.

Every time I do the deployment, the script did not run.

Can someone please help me with how to use them with parameters?

this is my code:

```
resource ps2 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommands@2022-11-01' = {
  parent: vm
  name: 'WithProtectedParameters'
  location: location
  properties: {
    parameters: [
      {
        name: 'master'
        value: '10.10.10.10'
      }
      {
        name: 'user'
        value: 'thomas'
      }
      {
        name: 'domain'
        value: 'company'
      }
    ]
    protectedParameters: [
      {
        name: 'password'
        value: dmaPassword //from keyvault
      }
    ]
    runAsPassword: adminPassword
    runAsUser: adminUsername
    source: {
      //script: '''.\myProgram.exe -m "${master}" -u "${user}" -p ${password} -d ${domain} '''
      script: '''New-Item -Path C:\AzureData\ -Name "${user}.txt" -ItemType File -Value "${domain},${master},${password}"'''
    }
  }
}
```

I tried these combinations:

$parameter, ${parameter}, "${parameter}", $ {parameter}

Answer (score 1):

In case it is Powershell on Windows, the parameters are passed to script as

`script.ps1 -paramName paramValue`

So your script will have to have a `param()` section

`param([string]$master) Write-Host $master`

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command-managed#create-or-update-run-command-on-a-vm-instance-using-parameter-and-protectedparameter-parameters-public-and-protected-parameters-to-script) talks about how the parameters are passed to the script.